# Convert WMI UTC time to unix time stamp using PHP

Tags: php, time, wmi, utc

I'm using PHP to make a WMI query to remote computers in my network.

I'm getting the LastBootupTime value using this:

```
$wmi_operatingsystem = $obj->ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem"); 
$lastreboot = $wmi_call->LastBootupTime;
```

My issue is that $lastreboot is something like 20130612032422.112393-360.  I need to convert this value to a unix time stamp or something human friendly. From what I've read I believe that's a time stamp in UTC format.  I've tried using strtotime, but that's not working for me.

HELP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`SWbemDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393687%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object to decode the UTC format.

```
 $wtime = new COM ("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime");  
 $wtime->Value = $wmi_call->LastBootupTime;
 //Now you can access the elements of the datetime using the SWbemDateTime properties  
 //like so $wtime->Year,$wtime->Month,$wtime->Day
```

Comment: Can you show me an example using the $lastreboot variable above? Thanks! @RRUZ

Comment: @DobotJr, try the `Hours` and `Minutes` properties, all is in the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393687%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. Also don't forget accept the answer.

Comment: @ruzz, if I can bother you once more.  I've read through the docs in the link you provided but can't find how to get AM or PM. Any ideas?

Comment: AFAIK the `Hours` property returns a value between 0 and 23, so you can check the value of this property to determine if is `AM` or `PM`